# When ReturnUrl loads last page after Login.It should load with all last values that i was working on?

Tags: asp.net, session, c#-4.0, cookies, authentication

I'm Using a returnurl cookie to store current Url when Login cookie expires,And when User Again login,It redirect user to last page he was working on.But all his work gone,all data gone.Is it possible when user comeback after login he get all his text-box data what he filled?

I have seen this Happening in Shopping Site where user can add-to-cart fill all details but can't Check out if not  login,when he do login he get all his data back as he left .
Note:*I don't want to use Session to store each and every data of page and fetch values when page reloads*
*I'm not Using windows form Authentication for login. I'm generating my own cookie*
Here's Code:In master Page  Userinfo() Checks cookies exist or not . And Linkbutton is logout Button

```
public void UserInfo()
    {
        HttpCookie LoginCredentialscookie = Request.Cookies["LoginCredentials"];
        if (Request.Cookies["LoginCredentials"] != null && LoginCredentialscookie != null && LoginCredentialscookie.Values != null && LoginCredentialscookie.Values["LoginID"] != null && LoginCredentialscookie.Values["Name"] != null)
        {
            lblUserName.Text = Request.Cookies["LoginCredentials"].Values["Name"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {

            Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery));

           Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
           Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
           Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
           Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        }
    }
    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie acookie = new HttpCookie("LoginCredentials");
        acookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
        Response.SetCookie(acookie);

        Response.Redirect("Eminent.aspx");

        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

    }
```

Here is Code in login.aspx

```
 HttpCookie returnCookie = Request.Cookies["returnUrl"];
                            if ((returnCookie == null) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnCookie.Value))
                            {
                                Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                HttpCookie deleteCookie = new HttpCookie("returnUrl");
                                deleteCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                                Response.Cookies.Add(deleteCookie);
                                Response.Redirect(returnCookie.Value);
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this recently, albeit using MVC.

The page saved the Object/Model in session, this was persisted into the database as serialized/deserialized XML.

Once the user logs back in, I set the session from the value saved into the database.

Further reading
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36781/Serialization-and-Deserialization-in-ASP-NET-with

Comment: I'm using asp.net Webform

Comment: The same logic applies, how are you currently setting the values of the textboxes ?

Comment: It is just simple Submit form. i'm filling values using aspx page.before submitting form i'm checking for authentication,if cookies expires user logs out,when again user login user must get all his previous values.